# XSLT: Loop through and get unique attribute value

Tags: xml, for-loop, foreach, xslt-1.0

I have to loop through `Main/MainLines/MainLine` and get sum(Quantity) `for-each` - `Item/ItemNo`.The output should have only one `MainLine` element for each `ItemNo`.The way I am doing I am getting repeated.

Input

```
<Main Company="ABC" MainNo="213211" >
  <MainLines>
    <MainLine Quantity="2"  Node="9999">
      <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW"/>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine Quantity="1"  Node="9999">
      <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW"/>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine Quantity="3"  Node="9999">
      <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW"/>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine Quantity="2"  Node="9999">
      <Item ItemNo="22222" Class="NEW"/>
    </MainLine>
  </MainLines>
</Main>
```

Output

```
<Main Company="ABC" MainNo="213211" Reason="NewFile">
  <MainLines>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="6">
      <MainLine Quantity="2" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="6">
      <MainLine Quantity="1" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="6">
      <MainLine Quantity="3" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="2">
      <MainLine Quantity="2" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="22222" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
  </MainLines>
</Main>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <Main>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Main/@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Reason">
      <xsl:value-of select="'NewFile'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <MainLines>

      <xsl:for-each select="Main/MainLines/MainLine">
        <MainLine>
          <xsl:variable name="ITEM_ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="Item/@ItemNo"/>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:attribute name="ExtnQuantity">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../MainLine[Item/@ItemNo = $ITEM_ID]/@Quantity)"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </MainLine>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </MainLines>
  </Main>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<Main Company="ABC" MainNo="213211" Reason="NewFile">
  <MainLines>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="6">
      <MainLine Quantity="2" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="123123" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
    <MainLine ExtnQuantity="2">
      <MainLine Quantity="2" Node="9999">
        <Item ItemNo="22222" Class="NEW" />
      </MainLine>
    </MainLine>
  </MainLines>
</Main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Muenchian grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping) problem.
You can solve it by iterating through the unique values of `ItemNo` only.
Here is an adapted version of your stylesheet:

Note that I have moved the `<MainLines>` element into its own template to reduce the nesting. Also, you can add attributes directly to an element, you don't need `<xsl:attribute>`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Define key -->
  <xsl:key name="ItemNoKey" match="MainLine/Item" use="@ItemNo" />

  <xsl:template match="/Main">
    <Main Reason="NewFile">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="MainLines"/>
    </Main>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MainLines">
    <MainLines>

      <!-- For each first MainLine with a given ItemNo -->
      <xsl:for-each select="MainLine[count(Item | key('ItemNoKey', Item/@ItemNo)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentItemNo" select="Item/@ItemNo"/>

        <!-- Print MainLine with quantity sum -->
        <MainLine ExtnQuantity="{sum(../MainLine[Item/@ItemNo = $CurrentItemNo]/@Quantity)}">

          <!-- Copy the selected MainLine element -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </MainLine>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </MainLines>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```